# Xcode 15 Import of C++ module 'Darwin.C.time' appears within extern "C" language linkage specification

Tags: xcode

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C"
{
#endif
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: have you? :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `-Wno-module-import-in-extern-c` to 'Apple CLang - Custom Compiler Flags -> Other C++ '

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me when I tried to archive a Flutter app.
the error disappears after run:

> Flutter clean

.